# Python Mechanize, how to get URL parameters

Tags: python, url, parameters, mechanize, mechanize-python

I'm currently working on website scraper. Because I have to log in to access the website, a `session ID` has to be generated and saved for further usage.

The `session ID` is at the end of the URL.

```
https://example.com/something.php?sid=123456789
```

I tried using the `geturl()` command but it only returns the URL without any parameters.

What would be the best way to get the url parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

parsed = urlparse(url)
print(parsed)
```

**The output:**

```
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='example.com', path='/something.php', params='', query='sid=123456789', fragment='')
```

Then, you can access:

```
print(parsed.query)
```

**The output:**

```
sid=123456789
```

Then, you can extract:

```
sid = parsed.query.split('sid=')[-1]
print(sid)
```

**The output:**

```
123456789
```